# CGAL triangulation over 3D points - trying to 'skin'

Tags: cgal, delaunay

I hope this is not too vague. I find the CGAl library quite difficult to understand and it may just be a difference in terminology that is confusing me.

I am trying to create a triangulation over a set of 3D points but I'm not sure I am using the correct functionality or just calling the wrong functions. I have used PCL's triangulation but the results are poor though the code is simple and straightforward. I am hoping CGAL can do better.

[image: Here is an example point set 'dolphin' read from an stl file]

I have tried using a simple triangulation like that given in the simple_triangulation_3 example. That should give triangles joining the input data points and no others. However, extracting the finite faces will result in some faces that give the convex hull over the points:

[image: convex hull over the points].

I have tried using the mesh creation but that adds many extra points which I also don't want. I have not got around to analysing the shape produced yet as I'm not sure how to get triangles from that rather than polygons.

So basically I wanted to check what should be the correct approach before looking at the procedure for getting the results and analysing the code.

Comment: Do you really want a triangulation or do you want to reconstruct the surface from the point set?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at surface reconstruction packages in CGAL, e.g.

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PkgPoissonSurfaceReconstruction3

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PkgScaleSpaceReconstruction3

Comment: Scale_space_surface_reconstruction_3 was exactly what I needed. Many thanks